# how I can compare and display a certain value in a array multidimensional cakephp

Tags: php, cakephp

I'am making a stock control system for sugar, I need to print and compare values, just have a problem when I want to printf a valor of a array multidimencional example, this is my array:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [Azucar] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 1
                    [nombre] => 21
                    [produccion] => verano.
                    [cantidad] => 10032.32
                    [fecha] =>
                )
            [grupo] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 2
                    [categoria] => azucar
                    [subcategoria] => ingenio
                    [created] => 2008-02-13 18:34:56
                )
            [AzucarExistencia] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                          (
                                 [id] => 1
                             [cantidad] => 3250
                             [cantidadtotal] => 325.12
                                 [sacarosa] => 32
                             [refinada] => 956
                   )
                    [1] => Array
                          (
                                 [id] => 2
                             [cantidad] => 4000
                             [cantidadtotal] => 564
                                 [sacarosa] => 12
                             [refinada] => 780
                  )
                    [2] => Array
                            (
                                 [id] => 3
                             [cantidad] => 4564
                             [cantidadtotal] => 654.32
                                 [sacarosa] => 5451
                             [refinada] => 45
                )
                     [3] => Array
                           (
                                 [id] => 4
                             [cantidad] => 3244
                             [cantidadtotal] => 21.1
                                 [sacarosa] => 123
                             [refinada] => 123.45
                )

                )
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
           [Azucar] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 2
                    [nombre] => 32
                    [produccion] => verano.
                    [cantidad] => 9032.32
                    [fecha] =>
                )
         [grupo] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 3
                    [categoria] => azucar
                    [subcategoria] => ingenio
                    [created] => 2008-02-13 18:34:56
                )
         [AzucarExistencia] => Array
                (
                     [0] => Array
                              (
                                     [id] => 6
                                 [cantidad] => 3250
                                 [cantidadtotal] => 325.12
                                     [sacarosa] => 32
                                 [refinada] => 956
                       )
                      [1] => Array
                             (
                                 [id] => 7
                             [cantidad] => 4000
                             [cantidadtotal] => 564
                                 [sacarosa] => 12
                             [refinada] => 780
                     )
                      [2] => Array
                             (
                                 [id] => 8
                             [cantidad] => 4564
                             [cantidadtotal] => 654.32
                                 [sacarosa] => 5451
                             [refinada] => 45
                     )
                       [3] => Array
                            (
                                 [id] => 9
                             [cantidad] => 3244
                             [cantidadtotal] => 21.1
                                 [sacarosa] => 123
                             [refinada] => 123.45
                )
                      [4] => Array
                             (
                                 [id] => 10
                             [cantidad] => 4564
                             [cantidadtotal] => 654.32
                                 [sacarosa] => 5451
                             [refinada] => 45
                        )
                      [5] => Array
                            (
                                 [id] => 11
                             [cantidad] => 3244
                             [cantidadtotal] => 21.1
                                 [sacarosa] => 123
                             [refinada] => 123.45
                   )

                )

        )

)
```

I need to compare all the values ​​within AzucarExistencia, the first foreach is so:

```
        <?php foreach ($azucares as $azucar): ?>
        <tr>
            <td style="text-align: center;"><?php echo $azucar['Azucar']['username']; ?></td>
            <td style="text-align: center;"><?php echo $azucar['Azucar']['nombre']; ?></td>
            <td style="text-align: center;"><?php echo $azucar['Azucar']['apellido']; ?></td>
            <td style="text-align: center;"><?php echo $azucar['Azucar']['email']; ?></td>
            <td style="text-align: center;"><?php echo $azucar['Grupo']['categoria']; ?></td>
            <td style="text-align: center;"><?php echo $azucar['Grupo']['subcategoria']; ?></td>

        </tr>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
        <?php unset($azucar); ?>
```

but then needed to compare values ​​within AzucarExistencia, try that:

```
        <?php foreach ($azucares as $azucar): ?>
        <tr>
            <td style="text-align: center;"><?php echo $azucar['Azucar']['username']; ?></td>
            <td style="text-align: center;"><?php echo $azucar['Azucar']['nombre']; ?></td>
            <td style="text-align: center;"><?php echo $azucar['Azucar']['apellido']; ?></td>
            <td style="text-align: center;"><?php echo $azucar['Azucar']['email']; ?></td>
            <td style="text-align: center;"><?php echo $azucar['Grupo']['categoria']; ?></td>
            <td style="text-align: center;"><?php echo $azucar['Grupo']['subcategoria']; ?></td>
            <?php foreach ($azucar as $azucarexistencia): ?>
                <td style="text-align: center;"><?php 
                if ($azucarexistencia['AzucarExistencia']['cantidad']<1500) {
                    echo 'peligro';
                }
                 ?></td>


        </tr>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
        <?php unset($azucar); ?>
```

now the error is

Undefined index: azucarexistencia

or

Undefined index: AzucarExistencia

checked with debugkit the values ,​​come okay it's just make a good foreach, I try but i dont now how.

model

```
<?php
/**
* 
*/

class Azucar extends AppModel
{
    public $name ='User';
    public $useTable = 'users';
    public $primaryKey = 'id';  
    public $belongsTo = 'Grupo';
    public $hasOne = 'Perfil';
    public $hasMany = array('Deposito','AzucarExistencia');

}
?>
```

controller

```
<?php
/**
* 
*/
class AzucaresController extends AppController
{

    public $components = array('Session','RequestHandler');

    public function index()
    {

        $this->loadModel('Azucar'); 

        $this->paginate = array(
        'conditions' => array('Grupo.categoria' => 'Azucar'),
        'limit' => 25
        );
        $this->set('azucares', $this->paginate('Azucar'));

    }

    public function logout() {
        $this->redirect($this->Auth->logout());
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: how does the controller look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php 
foreach ($azucares as $azucar){
   foreach ($azucar['AzucarExistencia'] as $azucarexistencia){
       if ($azucarexistencia['cantidad']<1500) {
           echo 'peligro';
       }
   }
}

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Replace the loop as so

```
<?php foreach ($azucar['AzucarExistencia'] as $azucarexistencia): ?>
    <td style="text-align: center;"><?php 
        if ($azucarexistencia['cantidad']<1500) {
            echo 'peligro';
        }
    ?></td>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</tr>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

What you were doing wrong was you were trying to loop through all indexes of `$azucar` so it would loop through `$azucar["Azucar"]` `$azucar["grupo"]` `$azucar["AzucarExistencia"]`
but only `$azucar["AzucarExistencia"]` needs to be looped through